# Creating X11VNC Server Initscript not successful on boot (manually started works)

Tags: debian, vnc, init-script, init.d

I have installed X11VNC and starting it on a running System (with X and XFCE running) in a terminal does work. I have written a startup script (used the skeleton in /etc/init.d/skeleton) for that. Runnin that script in a terminal after boot

```
service x11vnc start
```

does actually start the server. Although for some reason the process does not run in background, hence I cannot use the terminal anymore.

But main problem is: the server is started on boot and I don't quite know where to start looking for errors and I am not sure (if there are any) where the log files can be found which show errors.

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          x11vnc server
# Required-Start:    lightdm
# Required-Stop:     
# Default-Start:     5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 2 6
# Short-Description: 
# Description:       Start VNC Server
### END INIT INFO

#
# Please remove the "Author" lines above and replace them
# with your own name if you copy and modify this script.

# Do NOT "set -e"

# PATH should only include /usr/* if it runs after the mountnfs.sh script
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="Start VNC Server"
NAME=x11vnc
PASSWD=/etc/x11vnc.pass
LOGFILE=/var/log/x11vnc.log
DAEMON=/usr/bin/$NAME
DAEMON_ARGS="-display :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass"
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.2-14) to ensure that this file is present
# and status_of_proc is working.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been started
    #   1 if daemon was already running
    #   2 if daemon could not be started
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test> /dev/null \
        || return 1
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS \
        || return 2
    # Add code here, if necessary, that waits for the process to be ready
    # to handle requests from services started subsequently which depend
    # on this one.  As a last resort, sleep for some time.
}

#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been stopped
    #   1 if daemon was already stopped
    #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
    #   other if a failure occurred
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
    RETVAL="$?"
    [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Wait for children to finish too if this is a daemon that forks
    # and if the daemon is only ever run from this initscript.
    # If the above conditions are not satisfied then add some other code
    # that waits for the process to drop all resources that could be
    # needed by services started subsequently.  A last resort is to
    # sleep for some time.
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry=0/30/KILL/5 --exec $DAEMON
    [ "$?" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    return "$RETVAL"
}

#
# Function that sends a SIGHUP to the daemon/service
#
do_reload() {
    #
    # If the daemon can reload its configuration without
    # restarting (for example, when it is sent a SIGHUP),
    # then implement that here.
    #
    start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 1 --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
    return 0
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_start
    case "$?" in
        0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  stop)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
        0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  status)
    status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
    ;;
  #reload|force-reload)
    #
    # If do_reload() is not implemented then leave this commented out
    # and leave 'force-reload' as an alias for 'restart'.
    #
    #log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC" "$NAME"
    #do_reload
    #log_end_msg $?
    #;;
  restart|force-reload)
    #
    # If the "reload" option is implemented then remove the
    # 'force-reload' alias
    #
    log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
      0|1)
        do_start
        case "$?" in
            0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
            1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
            *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
        esac
        ;;
      *)
        # Failed to stop
        log_end_msg 1
        ;;
    esac
    ;;
  *)
    #echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload}" >&2
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart|force-reload}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac
```

Running `update-rc.d x11vnc defaults` didn't help. Also `ls /etc/rc?.d/` shows my script in a couple of the files.

But I get the following

```
$ insserv -n x11vnc
insserv: dryrun, not creating .depend.boot, .depend.start, and .depend.stop
$ insserv x11vnc # returnes no errors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking around for longer time, I finally found a solution.

Using `xinetd`. I removed the init script from `/etc/init.d/` again and did the following.

- `apt-get install xinetd`
- Create content into file `/etc/xinetd.d/x11vnc`

`service x11vnc
{
  type = UNLISTED
  disable = no
  socket_type = stream
  protocol = tcp
  wait = no
  user = root
  server = /usr/bin/x11vnc
  server_args = -inetd -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -display :0 -forever -bg -rfbauth         /etc/vncpasswd -shared -enablehttpproxy -forever -nolookup -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 
  port = 5900
}`

- `chmod a+x x11vnc`
- Restart and it was working.

The flag `-auth` depends on your login manager. If you need to find out where the flag should point for you use: `ps wwaux | grep auth`. This will print the path.

Found solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=363236).